# Reorder commits one of which is a merge

Tags: git

I would like to reorder two commits, one of which is a merge. So I would like to go from:

```
A
|\
B \
|  \
C   D
```

to

```
B
|
A
|\
C D
```

Is it possible and safe? Commits C and D have already been pushed, but A and B have not. `git rebase -i` seems to make each commit having one parent only...

Comment: You must *re-perform* the merge, as in Paul's answer below. While `git rebase` has a `-p` / `--preserve-merges` option, it's not wise to mix it with reordering commits, so, best to do it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
git reset --hard C
git merge D
git cherry-pick B
```